# How to make cmake select the "right" library

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake

Where multiple possible versions of a library exist, is there a way of ensuring `cmake` picks the "right" one?

For example: centOS7 comes with gcc 4.5.2, and includes /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.1.  I have compiled gcc 6.2.0 in /usr/local, and this includes /usr/local/gcc-6.2/libgfortran.so.3

However,

```
find_package(Gfortran REQUIRED)
```

Always finds the system `gfortran`. My "FindGfortran.cmake" file contains:

```
find_library(Gfortran_LIBRARY
  NAMES gfortran
  PATHS /usr/local/gcc-6.2/lib64
)
```

And I've set tried running `cmake` with:

```
LD_RUN_PATH='/usr/local/gcc-6.2/lib64' LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/gcc-6.2/lib64' CXXFLAGS='-L/usr/local/gcc-6.2/lib64' cmake  ..
```

But whatever I do, `cmake` picks up the /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.1 version (and then my code fails because it links, correctly, against a different library which is in turn linked against libgfortran.so.3).

I have a "workaround" in that I can edit my CMakeLists.txt file to include the line:

```
set (Gfortran_LIBRARIES /usr/local/gcc-6.2/lib64/libgfortran.so.3)
```

But this is rather rubbish, and means that I need to maintain different CMakeLists.txt files on different machines (so I can't commit the file to SVN) which seems to defy the point of using `cmake`.

There must be something stupid I'm doing wrong - can anyone advise?

Comment: Look into the source of the find module itself. `find_package` modules aren't necessarily intended for outside-the-box applications. They aren't standardized at all really, and usually are very thinly written to try to find libs in the `/usr/local` system folders. Sometimes there is a main search path you can set though, other times you need to write your own.

Comment: Remember the `HINTS` and `PATHS` flags to `find_library()` ["Specify directories to search in addition to the default locations"](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/find_library.html). Maybe you want to add `NO_DEFAULT_PATH`?

Comment: If you're specifically asking for advice on searching for the desired gfortran library, you might want to consider reframing your question.

Comment: @nega: `HINTS` and `PATHS` have **priority** over standard library paths, see search algorithm described in the documentation you refer to. But, as far as I know, CMake doesn't search so-versions (`.so.N`), it search only libraries with definite extension (`.so`). If there is no `libgfortran.so` under the *PATHS*, the option has no effect. As for the **forcing** the choice, the most direct way is to set `Gfortran_LIBRARY` *cache* variable. It is perfectly legal from the CMake view.

Comment: @Tsyvarev true, and speaking of the cache, maybe OP just needs to clear his cache between tests.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the suggestions. I'll try NO_DEFAULT_PATH - FYI I am clearing the cache between runs (in fact, I delete everything in the build dir). And no, it's not a gfortran question, that's just one example; I have it with other libraries too.
However, as @Tsyvarev says, I thought PATHS should take priority over the system paths, and yet it doesn't seem to be doing so (and indeed things like my $CPATH and $LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variables don't seem to be taken into account).

Comment: So, what about the  file `libgfortran.so` (**without so-version**) under `/usr/local/gcc-6.2/lib64/`? Does this file exist or not?

Comment: @Tsyvarev - yes, that file exists (although find_library is returning the .so.x file for some reason).

However - adding 'NO_DEFAULT_PATH' in my FindGfortran.cmake (and other affected files) has solved this issue. I don't know why the default path was taking priority over the PATHS, however it's working now. Thanks both.

Comment: I was wrong: Actually, only `HINTS` option have priority over standard library paths, `PATHS` option is used after all. This is clearly written in [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/find_library.html).

Comment: But the whole purpose of the question is still unclear for me. Do you want to write `CMakeList.txt` script once, and it will **always** search libraries under `/usr/local/gcc-6.2/lib64`? Or do you want to let user to hint your script (**without modifying it**) which libraries the user want to use? Are you an **author** of `FindXXX.cmake` scripts used in your project? Or do you want to get these scripts from somewhere and do want to *not modify them*?

Comment: OK, let me clarify:
I need to build the same software on different machines. Some machines have multiple versions of the same library (gfortran, libMinuit2 being the main ones), although the paths aren't the same on all machines.
I am the author of the FindXXX.cmake file; so I can doctor this on each machine. However, since the $CPATH and $LD_LIBRARY_PATH vars are set on each machine, I want cmake to use these, and the order in these. Then OS/gcc updates etc don't require a mod to the cmake /FindXXX files. I am guessing I've got the cmake vars around my neck somewhere, maybe?